# Adding the canny edges to the original image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have used the edge(I,'canny') function in matlab to find canny edges of an image I.
The function returns a logical array of 0's and 1's which indicates where does an edge exist or not at a particular pixel.

Now I want to add the canny based image to the original Image I something like IF = I + (canny image of I). Can some one help me out to perform this function in Matlab?
I mean suggest a heuristic to achieve what I intend to do

Thanks

Comment: You can add it directly like you say--but what are you trying to achieve? What would the composited image look like?

Comment: what i m trying to convey is that I would like is certain heuristic for combining the two. I have a binary image and a uint8 image.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both of the images to double, normalize in some way and use `+` . If the original image has 3 channels, use `bsxfun` instead of `+`